# Select box with video thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a select box with a video thumbnail. This could be done either through javascript or jquery. Is there an example for creating a custom html select box that can also show a video thumbnail?

Comment: I can't imagine what would it looks like. Did you draw some concept? I don't see anything useful on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer will much like this http://videolightbox.com/rq/select-thumbnail-for-embedding-video-in-html-2q.html

http://videolightbox.com/#demo  shows many demos also with **free download**

And also http://visuallightbox.com/wordpress-lightbox-catalyst.html also has cool stuff,that you will be interested in. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a custom dropdown menu.  You can't do that with the current  tag, unless the jquery plugin in replacing it entirely with its own css and markup.

Check out http://codecanyon.net/item/fh-mega-menu-jquery-bootstrap-3-mega-menu-plugin/6943538?ref=designingmedia

Cost $4 but might be worth it.  Their demo has a video in it.

I'm no affiliated in anyway.  You might find a free one somewhere online.  Just search "jquery css dropdown plugin"